# Most effective technique to detect changes in mesh-data's?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

What would be the most effective way to track changes in the user mesh-data's? I would like to receive a notification signal if a user mesh data has changed.

I see a few (fast) approaches possible:

- on depsgraph handler: Keeping track of all meshes vertex-count
- on depsgraph handler: Keeping track of all meshes bounding-boxes
- via msgbus: Overseeing if a user is entering edit/sculpt mode, on which mesh

But:

- Keeping track of BB & vertcount wouldn't work if the user is simply moving a vertex within the BB area
- Overseeing edit/sculpt mode could create false positives if the user is just toggling edit mode on/off

Did I miss something obvious? We could gather bmesh information, but I'm afraid this method would be much too slow.

Context: creating a live bridge between blender and a game engine. Extra points if the solutions can also detect changes in mesh attributes

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach i did not knew about, much more generic!

- on depsgraph handler: Overviewing depsgraph.updates with upd.is_updated_geometry

A mix of this and a custom mesh hash method would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

We could use numpy and `foreach_get` to get an accurate hash.
look fast enough? might be too slow, with such method, it is crucial that the hash calculation is done on key moments

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
from collections import defaultdict

mesh_vertices_hashes = defaultdict(int)

def mesh_hash(obj):
    vertex_count = len(obj.data.vertices)
    vertices_np = np.empty(vertex_count * 3, dtype=np.float32)
    obj.data.vertices.foreach_get("co", vertices_np)
    h = hash(vertices_np.tobytes())
    print(h)
    return h

@persistent
def base_mesh_modified_notifier(scene):
    global mesh_vertices_hashes

    for obj in scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            current_hash = mesh_hash(obj)

            if obj.name not in mesh_vertices_hashes:
                mesh_vertices_hashes[obj.name] = current_hash
            elif mesh_vertices_hashes[obj.name] != current_hash:
                print(f"Base mesh of {obj.name} has been modified.")
                mesh_vertices_hashes[obj.name] = current_hash


bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(base_mesh_modified_notifier)
```